# Trouble with telescoping algorithm question

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations

The following is the question I am having difficulty with currently:

$T(1) = 2$

$T(n) = T(n - 1) + n-1, n > 1$

I have started off by first setting $T(n) - T(n - 1) = n - 1$ and then subtracting $T(n-1) - T(n-2)$ from each side but I'm confused on how to move further from there. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you! :)

update:

would this be my final solution? 
[my final solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqEbA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Try doing the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n T(n)$

$T(1)= 2$

$T(2) = T(1) + (2-1)$

$\ldots$

$T(n) = T(n-1) +(n-1)$

Notice that you get $T(n) = 2+ (2-1) + (3-1) + \ldots + (n-1)$

From there is almost done

Answer (score 0):

notice that :

$$ T(n) = T(1) + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}  T(k+1) - T(k) =\\ 2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k = 2 + \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you! I updated my question with the answer I've concluded using your help, please let me know if I've gone about it correctly (if you can) thank you once again! :)

Comment: Yes it is correct.